# Is there a shortcut to hide everything else except the object that's selected?

Tags: interface, objects, 3d-view, shortcut

Is there anyway of doing this with a keyboard shortcut without manually hiding each object on the scenes panel?

I remember vaguely there was a way to do this in 3DS max.

Comment: This feature is called **Isolate Selection**, would be nice if you could add this to your question for other former 3ds Max users to find this question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Press <kbd>/</kbd> on the numpad for [Local View](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/Global_or_Local_View).

Press it again to go back and toggle it off.

Answer (score 14):

As [answered by AttackingHobo](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26843/599), you can use <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> to toggle [*Local view*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/Global_or_Local_View).
This will kind of do what you describe, and I prefer it to hiding other objects as it preserves object visibility settings for when you unhide everything.

However, you can also use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to set the viewport visibility of all unselected objects to hidden. <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> will set the viewport visibility to visible again.

Comment: I try to avoid using local view myself because i usually end up confusing myself badly; and the select inverse hide sequence would have been my answer. I didn't know about shift H though… is there an edit mode equivilant?

Comment: @StarWeaver Shift H works in edit mode for me...

Answer (score 5):

Although the other answers are correct, another possibility is to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to invert your selection and then pressing <kbd>H</kbd> to hide. This works also in EDIT mode.

Comment: Shift H works in edit mode too.